# Error while assigning id to accordion in laravel

Tags: email, laravel-5, accordion

I have added a code of accordion in my project. Till yesterday it was working fine today accordion is not working because there is space between id as shown in screen-capture from my project.
[image: The red boxes show that there is 3 spaces in id of accordion].

My code to show the accordion is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        @foreach($data as $from)
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading{{$from->id}}">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{{$from->id}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse{{$from->id}}">
                            {{$from->from}}
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse{{$from->id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading{{$from->id}}">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        {{$from->body}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there any changes i can make, to get rid of this error?

**EDIT:**

Controller that passes all variable.

```
public function show(){
    $data = Email::latest()->get();
    return view('emails.display',compact('data'));
}
```

Comment: Please add the Controller code, that passes is $from variable.

Comment: Just to check the $from->id is the primary key? I mean it has no spaces in the DB?

Comment: No there are no spaces in database

Comment: If you change `#collapse{{$from->id}}` to `{{'collapse' . $from->id}}` are you still getting the same error?

Comment: Thanks, changing `#collapse{{$from->id}}` to `{{'collapse' . $from->id}}` works!